# member variable detection based on sfinae not work

Tags: c++, sfinae

Given the following code. I want to detect any class that has an `age` member field based on sfinae.

```
template <typename>
struct Void {
  using type = void;
};

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct HasAge : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasAge<T, typename Void<decltype(declval<T>().age)>::type>
    : std::true_type {};

struct Empty {};

struct PrivatePerson {
 private:
  int age;
};

struct PublicPerson {
 public:
  PublicPerson() = default;
  int age;
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasPointer : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasPointer<T, typename Void<typename T::pointer>::type>
    : std::true_type {};

struct FancyPointer {
  using pointer = int;
};

struct HazardPointer {
  template <typename T>
  struct pointer {};
};

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  cout << boolalpha;

  cout << HasAge<Empty>::value << endl;           // false
  cout << HasAge<PrivatePerson>::value << endl;   // false
  cout << HasAge<PublicPerson>::value << endl;    // false

  cout << HasPointer<FancyPointer>::value << endl; // true
  cout << HasPointer<HazardPointer>::value << endl;// false
}
```

The above code can't detect whether any class has an `age` member field or not. It seems only the primary template is applied. But this strategy seems to work for typedef or using an alias inside a class. It could detect class defines a `pointer` type or not. Could anyone tell me why `age` detection failed? Thx.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/frMPEx3nh How are you compiling it?

Comment: @Bob__ Really appreciate your reply. I tried your url, it seems the problem doesn't exist. And my compiler is `Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)`. And I figure out that if I put `using namespace std` inside main, under the given compiler, HasAge<PublicPerson>::value still returns false. But once I put the `using namespace std` declaration out of main, this expression returns true. You may have a look of cppinsight url `https://cppinsights.io/s/08de4262`, it seems the partial specialization only for the std::false_type.

Comment: @Bob__ Oh, I see. I did't add the qualifier `std` before `declval`. Why the `clang` compiler doesn't detect this, the `gcc` compiler signals this is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted code, this template:

```
template <typename T>
struct HasAge<T, typename Void<decltype(declval<T>().age)>::type>
//                                      ^^^^^^^   
    : std::true_type {};
```

Is defined *before* a `using namespace std;` statement, which is in `main`.

Compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, we get errors:

```
<source>:14:41: error: 'declval' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::declval'?
   14 | struct HasAge<T, typename Void<decltype(declval<T>().age)>::type>
      |                                         ^~~~~~~
      |                                         std::declval
```

Clang, with the same arguments, emits a warning<sup>1</sup> instead:

```
<source>:14:41: warning: use of function template name with no prior declaration in
function call with explicit template arguments is a C++20 extension [-Wc++20-extensions]
struct HasAge<T, typename Void<decltype(declval<T>().age)>::type>
```

If we compile with `g++` using `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -fpermissive`, we obtain a similar warning and the same (unexpected) result<sup>2</sup> as OP's.

```
<source>:13:41: warning: there are no arguments to 'declval' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'declval' must be available [-fpermissive]
   13 | struct HasAge<T, typename Void<decltype(declval<T>().age)>::type>
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

To make this pre-C++20 detection idiom implementation work<sup>3</sup>, we just need to fully qualify `std::declval`.

---

<sup>1) https://godbolt.org/z/dPc5aMEr8</sup> 
<sup>2) https://godbolt.org/z/rP74hnKhs</sup> 
<sup>3) https://godbolt.org/z/94fqcTEs7</sup>